# docker container: can't access dotnet web api container from another container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have created dotnet core web API which runs in a docker container.

when I try to call the API from my browser (Chrom) I got the result, but when I try to call the API from an angular app which is also running in a docker container I got a connection_faild error.

the docker file for the web API :

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk
COPY /pub/ /root/
WORKDIR /root/
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Backend-lite.dll"]
```

to run the container:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 netcore-rest
```

docker file for the angular app:

```
FROM node:8.11.2-alpine as node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine
COPY --from=node /usr/src/app/dist/myapp /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.confs
```

to run the angular container:

```
docker run -t -p 80:80 angular
```

I'm using this connection string to connect to the API from the angular app

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/';
```

---

I have also tried to create a network between the two containers but it didn't work.

```
docker network create --gateway 172.16.1.1 --subnet 172.16.1.0/24 
app_subnet
```

then I ran the api container:

```
docker run --name server --ip 172.16.1.2 -p 5000:5000 --network 
app_subnet dotnet
```

the angular container :

```
docker run --name app --ip 172.16.1.3 -p 4200:80 --network app_subnet 
angular
```

and I changed the connection string in the angular app to match the container's IP

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://172.16.1.2:5000/api/';
```

I'm new to docker so can someone help me find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'http://host.docker.internal:5000/api/'

Localhost would be the loopback of the container but you want the host PC's port 5000

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion would be to use docker-compose as you are using two separate services. https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

In your angular container then you can use the service name instead of IP Address or localhost.

For your reference example 
https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular-Docker-Microservices/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: thank you, I did use docker-compose like in the example, but it didnt work!

Comment: Could you please share you docker-compose file